# Delay between new telegram channel messages and their stored datetime metadata

Tags: python, performance, telegram, pyrogram

I'm currently looking for the fastest way to read new messages from telegram channels I'm subscribed to. I wondered if I could use webhook, but it seems it's only possible for channels I'm the owner.
First I used Telethon and now I tried Pyrogram, hoping to improve the delay.
Here's my code:

```py
 @telegram_client.on_message(filters.chat(channels_id))
        async def new_message_listener(_, message):
            print(datetime.now() - message.date) # 2-3 seconds of delay in average
```

I started to make a research about the location of the Telegram servers maybe it can improve my latency if my code runs from closer data centers. Maybe python is too slow ?
Thank you very much for your help.